# JWT auth0 create jwt without certificate

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

I want to use json web tokens from [auth0](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken) without any authentication/signature for nodeJS. I know it is possible to define the 'alg' to be 'none' when creating the token like so:

```
var token = jwt.sign({ foo: 'bar' }, cert, { algorithm: 'none'});
```

But since I'm not using any signing, how could I create the token without the 'cert' part? I guess it is expecting for me to insert a private key. But since I wouldn't be using it for anything, I don't see what's the point?

Comment: Probably you already know this, but just to be sure: If you use the JWT to store a security-related state on the client and it is not signed, the client can change the JWT to include any scope, login-state etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass `null`:

```
var token = jwt.sign({ foo: 'bar' }, null, { algorithm: 'none'});
```

Comment: Thanks, I will test this soon!